# How to determine if a shell script file is sourced in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to how to determine if a script file is executed or sourced.

For example,

```
# Shell script filename build.sh
if [ "x$0" = "xbash" ]; then
    echo "I am sourced by Bash"
else
    echo "I am executed by Bash"
fi
```

If I typed

```
source build.sh
```

it would output *I am sourced by Bash*.

If I typed

```
./build.sh
```

it would output *I am executed by Bash*.

Currently, I use $0 to do this. Is there a better idea?

Inspired by Tripeee, I found a better way:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "x$(awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<< $0)" = 'xcdruntime' ]; then
    echo Try to source me, not execute me.
else
    cd /opt/www/app/pepsi/protected/runtime
fi
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, since you can run a script via `bash build.sh`. Also note that a script may source itself -- that's kinda stupid, but possible.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 eh... I have tried  `bash build.sh`   my solution still works

Comment: Interesting: don't ever call your sourced script `bash` or you will get confused!

Comment: You don't need the `x` markers to guard against empty strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work if sourced by another script. I would go the other way around;

```
test "X$(basename -- "$0")" = "Xbuild.sh" || echo Being sourced
```

Update: added X prefix to both strings.

Update too: added double dash to `basename` invocation.

Comment: Yeh, Your sulution is better than mine. If the script is sourced by another script, $0 will not be `bash`

Comment: I have to say that your solution is not the best one, it works fine on ubuntu, but it failed on Enterprise Linux 5. On ubuntu, when source a script file, $0 is `bash`, whereas on EL5, the $0 is `-bash`. when basename met -bash, an error occur

Comment: Ooops, you're right. Updated my answer. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: $(basename -bash) will raise an error. I replace basename with awk. see my update in my question. thank you

Comment: Actually you can use `$(basename -- "$0")` to work around that.  The double dash is undocumented in my version of `basename` but a widely supported convention.

Comment: after reading the source of basename.c and googleing, I find the double dash is documented here  [Get-Opt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) (: By saying `The double dash is undocumented in my version of basename`, did you mean that you are the author of basename?

Comment: No, I mean in the `coreutils` package I have installed on my workstation.

Comment: You don't need to prefix the strings with "X". As long as you quote them both, `test` will correctly handle any string you throw at it, whether it's empty or starts with a dash.

Comment: Reasonably modern versions of `test` cope with values which start with a dash, but this wasn't always true.